# Rendering views in other places in Yii2 - no renderPartial?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I need to render a partial view inside a custom component file in `Yii2` and according to the [Yii docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#rendering-in-other-places) you can access the view instance via something like this:

```
\Yii::$app->view->renderFile('@app/views/site/license.php');
```

I went ahead and tried:

```
Yii::$app->view->renderPartial('//my/view/');
```

...but then got an error that I was trying to access a non-existent method.

I then checked out the [view class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html) and noticed it doesn't have a `renderPartial` and this is a method of the [controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html) class instead.

I see it has a `renderFile` method and a `render` method; which of these should I use?

The docs don't state the `render` method includes the layout like the method of the same name from the *controller* class, so I'm not sure; as for *renderFile* I'm not 100% sure if that is suitable either?

Could someone explain which method would produce the same results that `renderPartial` produces?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can call `renderPartial` from `Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('myview');` Also as you can see from [source code of yii\base\Controller](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Controller.php#L400) `renderPartial` calls View's `render` method so you can use `Yii::$app->view->render`. Basically there is no difference between `render` and `renderFile`, because `render` internally calls `renderFile`. But when you use `render` you can pass `$view` in several formats like *path alias*, *absolute path whithin application* or *whithin module* and *relative path*. And to `renderFile` you can pass only absolute file path or path alias.